# viewpager + webview, how to  stop webview loading

Tags: android, webview, android-viewpager

Hi,

I have created an app that uses ViewPager and all pages contain WebViews.
Every Webview contains server images, videos, mp3 ...

The WebView settings are

```
      public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
            .
            .
            .

            final RelativeLayout imageLayout  = (RelativeLayout)         
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.omb_webview_layout, null);
            WebView webview = (WebView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.video_view);
            ProgressBar pbImage = (ProgressBar) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

            webview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
            webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
            webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            webview.setWebViewClient(new mWebViewClient());
            webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
            webview.clearCache(true);
            webview.clearHistory();
            if(Pbar != null) {
                webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                 public  void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)     {
                  Log.i(TAG, "webview loading progress : "+ progress);
                    if(progress == 100) {
                        try {
                            Pbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "timer progress GONE : "+ progress,e);
                        }
                         }
            });
            }
```

The problem is when pages are swiped then also this line

```
 Log.i(TAG, "webview loading progress : "+ progress);
```

is executing which means that webviews are loading in background.
If I swipe 4 or more pages all webviews are loading.

```
     destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object o) {
    Log.d("DESTROY", "destroying view at position sheetal " + position);

            RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout)o;

                    WebView tmp = webviewDictionary.get(position);;

            tmp.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
                            tmp.stopLoading();
        if(tmp != null){
                        Log.i(TAG, "sheetal webview is destroyed " +position );
                        try {
                            tmp.onPause();

                            tmp.loadDataWithBaseURL("about:blank", "<html></html>","text/html", "UTF-8", null);
                            tmp=null;
                            //  tmp.destroy();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "webview destroyed Exception 0" ,e);
                        }
                    }
```

How to stop background loading if the pages are not visible? setOffscreenPageLimit(1)(means 3 page prev,cur,next),

In Viewpager, 2 page (means 1 position page) is not loading properly. It shows a blank white page, how do I solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i have used stopLoading(), but it dose not stop the background loading, whenever destroyItem(...) is called webview stop the loading right?  but wont stop loading.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but don't you need to set the OffscreenPageLimit to 0?

Comment: i tried pager.OffscreenPageLimit(0) but doesn't  work .

Comment: So, your stuck with 3 pages in memory? This means that the previous and next page won't be destroyed and keep loading. In that case I suggest you keep track of previous and next pages and call stopLoading() on those yourself.

Comment: yes, i am stuck with 3 pages in memory, i have storing active  3 pages in a  dictionary, whenever any pages goes out of scope i am calling  stopLoading() for particular page or activity is finished i am calling  stopLoading() for all page;  but it doesn't stop loading...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this solved my problem.

i have created a dictionary, it contains 3 webview with position as key.

here i am adding webviews in dictionary

```
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    .
    .
    .
    webviewDictionary.put(position, webView);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

cleaning webviews is from dictionary

```
public void cleanAllWebViews() {

    try {

        if(webviewDictionary != null){

            Iterator<Integer> webViewIterator = webviewDictionary.keySet().iterator();

            while(webViewIterator.hasNext()) {

                Integer key=(Integer)webViewIterator.next();

                WebView webView = (WebView) webviewDictionary.get(key);


                webView.stopLoading();
                //                  webView.pauseTimers();

                webView.setWebChromeClient(null);
                webView.setWebViewClient(null);


                webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("about:blank", "<html></html>","text/html", "UTF-8", null);
                webViewIterator.remove();

            }
        }

        webviewDictionary = null;


    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ombook last call onPauseAllWebviews  Exception",e  );
    }
}

    and 

    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    cleanAllWebViews();

    System.gc();

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried "OffscreenPageLimit" set to 1 ? 0 is an invalid value according to this post:
[ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0) doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073214/viewpager-setoffscreenpagelimit0-doesnt-work-as-expected)

also , have you tried to handle some events of switching between the pages , so that each time you switch a page , the current page's webview will stop loading , or start loading an empty html file?

Comment: yes, while navigating the pages i have pausing the webview (webview.onPause())

Comment: did it work? if so, can you please publish the relevant code?