# android Viewpager Only load one page one time

Tags: android, android-viewpager

[ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0) doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073214/viewpager-setoffscreenpagelimit0-doesnt-work-as-expected)

Like the question. But I need a custom Viewpager which  load one page on time.
Is there any example?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can do this with following steps

- First create a `count` variable in the adapter class
- second in the `ViewPager` Adapter make a `public` function say `setCount()`
- and in the override `getCount()` function of Adapter `return` the `count`
  variable
- now `override` the on `pageScroll()` function of the `ViewPager` when the
  user flips the page you can call the `setCount()` to increase the `count`
  of the count variable
- also check that if that the current `index` is last and page is
  scrolled to left

this should work .

Comment: It's a great Idea.  do you have sample Code.

Comment: please send some code for this, your idea is looking good , if possible pls attach some code

Comment: if you have come back from your office now, can you please post it?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to achieve (if it is just about saving memory or lowering loading time), you can also load all pages as usual but load the content of the fragment only when it actually gets displayed.

Comment: your solution can't solve my problem. because， the Views within viewpager may have dependency Relationship. for example, the Seconde View's content my depend  the first view's result which get from web.

Comment: I am adding youtube video on every viewpager but it wan't work as view pager load next page as well .. so i need only one page to be load