# Viewpager called multiple times

Tags: android, android-viewpager

android View pager load two pages at a time into memory.i want to load one page at a time and call when page scrolled is it possible?

how can i load one page at a time when user scrolled then call second fragment?

Comment: Have you searched any where?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android Viewpager Only load one page one time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718038/android-viewpager-only-load-one-page-one-time)

Comment: i have searched everywhere but i can't figure out i have to call service on page scrolled but on a first time it call two service and one time on second page .on third page it called nothing

i want to call service every time when page is scrolled

Comment: post your code. check this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What do you want? what you have tried?

Comment: i have posted my code below

Comment: heloo nirav i have posted my code below that i have tried.

Answer (score 0):

actually it is 3. view pager always load 3 pages or to be exact 3 fragments into memory. this insures user doesn't encounter a frame drop. but there is a catch:

we have two kind of view pager adapter: `FragmentPagerAdapter` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` .

if you have fragments with heavily content i suggest `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` because it doesn't load all 3 fragments together. it loads the first one and the save only the states of the other two. its better in case you want to manage memory for heavily content Fragments

Comment: is there any solution for load one page at a time and call second page when user scrolled