# how to disable preloading nextpage in Viewpager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

How do I disable  page pre loading in Viewpager??

I tried

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0)
```

but it's not working.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10073916/3134215

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19097056/4180965).

According to [Ali Imran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1325942/ali-imran) you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13718219/4180965):

1. First create a count variable in the adapter class
2. second in the ViewPager Adapter make a public function say `setCount()`
3. and in the override `getCount()` function of Adapter return the count variable
4. now override the on `pageScroll()` function of the ViewPager when the
   user flips the page you can call the `setCount()` to increase the
   count of the count variable
5. also check that if that the current
   index is last and page is scrolled to left

Comment: @TejjD  Which is the pageScroll() method you are referring to?
can you post code to complete this functionality.

Comment: can u elaborate in code please ?

Answer (score 1):

use this `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1)` instead of `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0)` . because the minimum value of `setOffscreenPageLimit()` is 1.

Comment: Thank you. it is another problem. >_< i'm solved