# 3 android fragments in viewpager, how to keep them all alive?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I have a viewpager with at least 3 fragments.  If the user inputs data into A, then B, then C and goes back to A that data is lost from A.

I think I read somewhere that this has to do with memory management and since fragments only connect to or store adjacent fragments it's killing A when I get too far away.
However I wish to retain the life of each fragment even were I to have >3.

How can I tell the viewpager to never kill a fragment unless explicitly directed?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

use

```
setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit)
```

on the ViewPager object.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)):

> [It set]s the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state.

Comment: thanks a lot it is really helpful, I had 6 tabs and I wanted to maintain data of my first fragment and spent 2 days for it :) .

Comment: This really helps. My fragments were losing states too. Any other tips you'd like to suggeat or anything I should keep in mind while using this property ?

Comment: Note that if you want to do the opposite and make sure your fragments are killed and restored according to the lifecycle, this will not help, because the [minimum `limit` is `1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10073916/11683) meaning at least 3 fragments are kept alive at all times.