# Load only one Fragment in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have used `ViewPager` with `Fragment`.
But it loads two pages at time.
Is there any way to load only one page in viewpager ?

Comment: Have a look on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44405015/7874047

Answer (score 4):

This might be the thing you are looking for:

```
  mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(n); // where n is the number of offscreen pages you want to load.
```

**The minimum value of it can be "1" as you said. ** check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10073916/1567588) and also read the comments.

Answer (score 3):

setOffScreenPageLimit method has a limit of minimum 1.
If you'll try to set smaller limit than this, it will use its default value which is 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do manual your adapter such as

```
public int currentIndex;

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    if(position == currentIndex){
        return new EmptyFragment();
    }else{
        return new YourNormalFragment();
    }
}
```

and becareful to modify

```
    yourViewPager.setCurrentItem(index);
```

along with

```
    yourAdapter.currentIndex = index;
```

Comment: I don't think this this would work. getItem will be called twice with index and index+1 depending on how you swipe your views