# Call Fragment's OnCreate when page is fully selected

Tags: android, android-fragments

My app contains a ViewPager which holds 5 fragments. When fragment 1 is visible, it also calls fragment 2's onCreate method. I tried using `onAttach`, `onMenuVisibility`, etc. But I don't like how these perform in my app.

Is there a way to disable a fragment's onCreate being called when the adjacent fragment is visible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17611796/2308683

Comment: @cricket_007 Not sure what I would do without you

Answer (score 0):

ViewPager is loading next and previous pages accordingly to `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit()`. **Default and min value is 1.**

Answer (score 0):

What I've found about it's that you need at least 1 fragment offset (check setOffscreenPageLimit()).

You can have a placeholder fragment if you want. But as viewpager enables you to swipe left/right, android always want to show a smooth movement to the side pages and that requires having the page previously loaded.

You can find more about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10073916/3976716