# Update Fragment from ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an `Activity` with a `ViewPager`. I also have a `Dialog` that will retrieve a list with some items that the user will choose. Now, how can I update the `Fragment` where the Items are supposed to display as new views attached to this Fragment?

Here is my `ViewPager`'s adapter:

```
public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new Fragment1();

        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, here is the `Fragment`:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public ViewGroup onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen1, container, false);
    }
    return view;
}

}
```

This is the method that I want to use to add Items to my `Fragment`

```
private void addItem() {

    // Instantiate a new "row" view.

    final ViewGroup[] newViews = new ViewGroup[selectedItems.length];


    for(int i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++){
        newViews[i] = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
                    R.layout.animated_layout_item, mContainerView, false);

        // Set the text in each new row.
        ((TextView) newViews[i].findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(selectedItems[i]);

        // Because mContainerView has android:animateLayoutChanges set to true,
        // adding this view is automatically animated.

            mContainerView.addView(newViews[i], 0);


        // Set a click listener for the "X" button in the row that will remove the row.
        OnClickListener listener = new MyAddItemListener(newViews[i], mContainerView, this);
        newViews[i].findViewById(R.id.delete_button).setOnClickListener(listener);

    }


}
```

Comment: Why do you have "ViewGroup view = view = " in Fragment1 onCreateView?

Comment: It's a typo. Let me correct it. Thanks for noticing it.

Comment: https://github.com/pchauhan/RefreshFragementViewPager

Answer (score 139, accepted):

> Update Fragment from ViewPager

You need to implement `getItemPosition(Object obj)` method.

This method is called when you call

```
notifyDataSetChanged()
```

on your `ViewPagerAdaper`. Implicitly this method returns `POSITION_UNCHANGED` value that means something like this:
*"Fragment is where it should be so don't change anything."*

So if you need to update **Fragment** you can do it with:

- Always return `POSITION_NONE` from `getItemPosition()` method. It which
  means: *"Fragment must be always recreated"*
- You can create some update() method that will update your
  Fragment(fragment will handle updates itself)

---

**Example of second approach:**

```
public interface Updateable {
   public void update();
}


public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements Updateable {

   ...

   public void update() {
     // do your stuff
   }
}
```

And in FragmentPagerAdapter you'll do something like this:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
   MyFragment f = (MyFragment ) object;
   if (f != null) {
      f.update();
   }
  return super.getItemPosition(object);
}
```

And if you'll choose first approach it can looks like:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
   return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

**Note:** It's worth to think a about which approach you'll pick up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, it is not updating it! Could you take a look at it in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/lumalav/6167821) that I just created? I chose option 2.

Comment: Also, when I try to call notifyDataSetChanged(), it tells me that is undefined for the type ViewPager

Comment: @LuisLavieri you should call it like `yourPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Thanks @Sajmon, but it is throwing a [Null Pointer Exception](https://gist.github.com/lumalav/6167821/raw/af7b13e10a4a994aaa73dc504ea8e88e011dde1e/NullPointerException) when I call it. :( What do you think it might be?

Comment: @LuisLavieri you need to call it after you instantiated adapter and viewpager and added adapter to pager.

Comment: Sure, I'm calling it in myDialogListener. But, after instantiated them. Like this: mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
   
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

Comment: The ViewPager works fine at first, but the NPE is thrown after I click "OK" in my Listener

Comment: Beautiful. After hard work, it finally worked. Thanks buddy. The problem was my `mContainerView`; it wasn't instantiated properly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35039/discussion-between-luis-lavieri-and-sajmon)

Comment: +1 for @Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
   return POSITION_NONE;
}

Comment: I am using the second method, but I my fragment is not updating... From debug, I can clearly see the the adapter for my fragment's listview is updated. The one issue remains is that the fragment in the viewpager is not updated Any idea?

Comment: @Sajmon  I have 2 fragments in FragmentPagerAdapter. But I want to recreate only One fragment onResume() of the MainActivity. Any idea on how to recreate one fragment out of the two?

Comment: It's a really elegant solution for me to update fragment, I select "update" solution since that I want to reuse fragment without create a new fragment instance every time.  Thanks very very much :)

Comment: @Sajmon I follow your steps but has a strange problem: `getItemPosition()` called more than one times after `notifyDataSetChanged()` called. This cause `f.update()` called many times too, but it should be called once! Would you please give me some tip, thanks.

Comment: This works best - not returning `return super.getItemPosition(object)` but returning `POSITION_NONE `  Thank you

Comment: this is biggest problem of viewpager adapter

Comment: I have 5 fragment in FragmentPagerAdapter. I have tried both solution but none of worked for me as MyFragment called multiple times every time i swipe. Please help if anyone found solution.

Comment: it's working great :) btw can you please explain, what does `return POSITION_NONE` do ? and why `getItemPosition` ?

Comment: Small suggestion: For getItemPosition in the FragmentPagerAdapter, perhaps better to cast to `Updateable` instead of `MyFragment`, i.e.: `MyFragment f = (MyFragment) object;` -> `Updateable f = (Updateable) object;`?

Comment: Whats the ViewPager2 equivalent?

Answer (score 33):

I faced problem some times so that in this case always **avoid FragmentPagerAdapter and use FragmentStatePagerAdapter.**

It work for me. I hope it will work for you also.

Comment: thank you :) I could create dynamic tab  using this adapter

Answer (score 15):

I implement a app demo following Sajmon's answer.
Just for anyone else who search this question.

You can access source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/li2/Update_Replace_Fragment_In_ViewPager)

[image]

Answer (score 14):

In your PagerAdapter override getItemPosition

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
// POSITION_NONE makes it possible to reload the PagerAdapter
return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

After that add **viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();** this code like below

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

should work.

Comment: It works, but the UI starts getting slower when swipping between tabs. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can update the fragment in two different ways,

**First way**

like @Sajmon

You need to implement `getItemPosition(Object obj)` method.

This method is called when you call

```
notifyDataSetChanged()
```

You can find a example in [Github](https://github.com/CabezasGonzalezJavier/CommunicatingActivityWithFragmentsTabBar) and more information in this [post](http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/communicating-activity-with-fragments-in-tabbar-2/#sthash.jPZCqJLO.LzcU74z1.dpbs).

[image]

**Second way**

My approach to update fragments within the viewpager is to use the `setTag()` method for any instantiated view in the `instantiateItem()` method. So when you want to change the data or invalidate the view that you need, you can call the `findViewWithTag()` method on the ViewPager to retrieve the previously instantiated view and modify/use it as you want without having to delete/create a new view each time you want to update some value.

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Object object = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    if (object instanceof Fragment) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) object;
        String tag = fragment.getTag();
        mFragmentTags.put(position, tag);
    }
    return object;
}

public Fragment getFragment(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String tag = mFragmentTags.get(position);
    if (tag != null) {
        fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    }
    return fragment;
}
```

You can find a example in [Github](https://github.com/CabezasGonzalezJavier/RefreshCurrentFragmentWithinViewPager) or more information in this [post](http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/update-fragment-viewpager/#sthash.za1ZxJk5.dpbs%22):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Very simple to override the method in the fragment:

```
@Override

public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if(isVisibleToUser){
        actionView();
    }
    else{
        //no
    }      
}
```

Comment: Currently this answer is deprecated, check the Simon answer, that is more correct.

Answer (score 3):

**Accepted answer is not understand, That's why added easy solution.** after long struggle 
**find Working solution.**

Just **notify to your adapter**, it's working amazing,

> Reference code

```
 void setAdapter(int position) {
        PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        // when notify then set manually current position.
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

> call this code when you set adapter and when you want to refresh UI.

**In Your fragment add this code for refresh**

```
((YourActivityName) getContext()).setAdapter(selectedTabPosition);
```

*Use `instanceof` for cast context.*

*This code share only helping purpose who find solution.*

Answer (score 2):

A very simple yet effective solution to **update your fragment views**. Use `setUserVisibleHint()` method. It will be called upon when the fragment is about to be visible to user. There you can update our view (`setText()` or `setVisibility()` etc.)

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if(isVisibleToUser){
       //Write your code to be executed when it is visible to user
    }
}
```

It worked in my case. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you use Kotlin, you can do the following:

**1. On first**, you should be create `Interface` and implemented him in your `Fragment`

```
interface RefreshData {
    fun refresh()
}

class YourFragment : Fragment(), RefreshData {
    ...
    override fun refresh() {
        //do what you want
    }
}
```

**2. Next step** is add `OnPageChangeListener` to your `ViewPager`

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) { }

    override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
        viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        viewPager.currentItem = position
    }

    override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) { }
})
```

**3.** override `getItemPosition` in your `Adapter`

```
override fun getItemPosition(obj: Any): Int {
    if (obj is RefreshData) {
        obj.refresh()
    }
    return super.getItemPosition(obj)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i had 4 Fragments in the ViewPager, but i wanted to update just one Fragment  "FavoriteFragment" at the position 0 of the viewPager, every time the user click on this fragment.
but none of the codes above helped me reload just the one Fragment i want. 
so i tried this and it works for me:

in my FavoriteFragment i overrided onResume()

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        updateUI(); // code to update the UI in the fragment
    }
```

in the Activity hosting the viewPager override `addOnPageChangeListener()` and add this code

```
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);

                if(position == 0) { // 0 = the first fragment in the ViewPager, in this case, the fragment i want to refresh its UI
                    FavoritesFragment fragment = (FavoritesFragment) mViewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(mViewPager, position); 
                    fragment.onResume(); // here i call the onResume of the fragment, where i have the method updateUI() to update its UI
                    mViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
```

and it works perfect for me, to refresh/reload just the one fragment i want.

Comment: Thank you for sharing solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Alot of answers, but a quick and dirty solution that got the job done for me is having a method to init your pagerAdapter in your MainActivity:

```
public void initPagerAdapter(){
        pagerAdapter = new MainPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

In my fragment where I want to refresh, I just get the MainActivity and call that method:

```
MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getContext();
activity.initPagerAdapter();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your method for adding items into fragment should be *public* (placed in desired Fragment) and should have parameter the same type as selectedItems ..

That will make it visible from activity, which will have selectedItems array and voila..

p.s. better name it `addItemsFromArray(typeOfSelectedItems[] pSelectedItems)` cause name `addItem()` is quite undescriptive

Edit: stackoverflow just suggested similar topic :) Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7393477/304270) for detailed idea implementation.. :)

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a handler in the fragment that you want to update.

```
public static Handler sUpdateHandler;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...

        sUpdateHandler = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                // call you update method here.
            }
        };
    }
```

2) In the Activity/Fragment/Dialog, wherever you want the update call to be fired, get the reference to that handler and send a message (telling your fragment to update)

```
// Check if the fragment is visible by checking if the handler is null or not.
Handler handler = TaskTabCompletedFragment.sUpdateHandler;
if (handler != null) {
    handler.obtainMessage().sendToTarget();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because none of the above answers did the trick for me, here is my solution:

I combined the `POSITION_NONE` with loading on `setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)` instead of `onStart()`

As seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25676323/497366

In the `Fragment`:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        // load data here
    }else{
       // fragment is no longer visible
    }
}
```

and in the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` as seen in the top answer here from Simon Dorociak https://stackoverflow.com/a/18088509/497366:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

Now the fragments reload the data into their views everytime they are shown to the user.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Activity:

```
for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
    if (fragment.isVisible() && fragment instanceof MyFragment) {
        ((MyFragment) fragment).refreshContent();
        break;
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
public void refreshContent() {
    //refresh content
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To refresh the fragment in ViewPager. You can reload the ViewPager declaration function (I tried and succeeded):

```
public static void loadViewPager() {
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(context);
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
}
```

Call in another activity or fragment:

```
(Activity or Fragment).loadViewPager();
```