# Passing data to fragment in ViewPager and updating it

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, bundle, updates

I run into the problem where i have received some new data in my MainActivity and wish to pass it to a fragment inside a ViewPager. The only solution i can think of right now is to create a new ViewPager Adapter with the new data. like:

```
adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), MainActivity.this, bundle);
```

And in my ViewPager Adapter, i would further pass this bundle towards the fragment:

```
    @Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(arg0){
    case 0: 
        NewBooksFrag newBookFrag = new NewBooksFrag();
        newBookFrag.setArguments(b);
        return newBookFrag;
```

The downside of this method is that i have to create a new adapter every time new data comes in. I am just wondering if there is a better method out there.

I have read about the

```
adapter.notifydatasetchange()
```

which calls the

```
getitemposition(Object object)
```

and then i can implement a interface which updates the object

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088076/update-fragment-from-viewpager)

but the problem with this method is i do not know how to pass the data to the fragment i wish to update.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Let fragment take the data if you do not know how to pass it. In fragment, you create update() function that take the data from somewhere (e.g, getData() form a class). The update function is called when

```
adapter.notifydatasetchange();
```

and when you override:

```
getitemposition(Object object)
```

This data is to be updated and it should also include a field to address the fragment who should use this data (E.g, You can assign each fragment an ID).