# Separate instances of the same fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-adapter

I've an `Activity` with a `ViewPager`, 3 tabs, 3 `Fragment`s, and these fragments are all the same class but with different arguments when created so they are filled with a different list each one.

`MainActivity` > `SectionsPageAdapter`

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(MyFragment.TYPE, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

The problem is that I need to refresh the `Adapter` of an individual `Fragment` `onClick`, but the adapter is always the last created `Fragment` `Adapter`.

How can I solve this without duplicating the fragment class 3 times with different names?

Comment: Your approach is not very good. Please have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088076/update-fragment-from-viewpager?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung I want to use notifyDataSetChanged() on the list adapter inside the fragment, not on the ViewPager adapter, also getItemPosition(Object obj) on the ViewPager is never triggered.

Comment: Where is this `onClick` method? In the `Activity`? And are you trying to refresh the list within the `Fragment`?