# View pager different results

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager

I am using view pager with 3 tabs in `MainActivity` of my app to show grid images. I have one `MovieFragment` for all 3 tabs and I am using `FragmentsPagerAdapter` to create new instance of `MovieFragment` everytime tab is changed.

```
//FragmentsPagerAdapter method
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0: return MoviesFragment.newInstance(buildUrl(Utility.POPULAR_URL));
        case 1: return MoviesFragment.newInstance(buildUrl(Utility.RATED_URL));
        case 2: return MoviesFragment.newInstance("favorite");
        default: return null;
    }
}

//Fragment method
public static MoviesFragment newInstance(String uri){
    MoviesFragment fragment = new MoviesFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("fragment", uri);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}
```

Now I was getting different results in my app so I debugged this method and I found it calls methods before tab is selected i.e when I open app it creates instances for `case 0 and case 1` and when I go to `second tab` it creates instance for `case 2`.
Now in my second tab when I make changes to database and try to get them in third tab changes are not reflected as it already created instance of `third tab` when second tab was selected. 
How do I solve this problem?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18088509/4848308

Answer (score 0):

@Sahil This is because in android [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) keeps track of previous and next pages only. So when you initialize the viewPager it automatically create first 2 page and call `MoviesFragment` for 1st two tab. And once you start scrolling through, it starts keeping the track of only previous and next page.

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))

Comment: i changed that limit to 0 but still its same behavior

Comment: @Sahil you can handle your database function through `OnPageChangeListener` by defining a function, as android will always call the immediate next and previous pages.