# Updating android fragment inside an event

Tags: android, android-fragments, bluetooth, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I am doing an indoor localization app which is based on beacons. In my application, I have loaded 3 tabs in a ViewPager. The 2nd tab is a Map fragment which should display the map of the location the user is in based on the beacon signal.

```
public class Shop extends AppCompatActivity implements IndoorsLocationListener, ProximityManager.ProximityListener {

    private static final String TAG = Shop.class.getSimpleName();
    private IndoorsSurfaceFragment indoorsFragment;
    private ProximityManagerContract proximityManager;
    private ScanContext scanContext;
    TabPagerAdapter adapter;
    ViewPager viewPager;


    // TODO : Add more event types like devices updated
    private List<EventType> eventTypes = new ArrayList<EventType>() {{
//        add(EventType.DEVICES_UPDATE);
        add(EventType.DEVICE_DISCOVERED);
    }};

    private IBeaconScanContext beaconScanContext = new IBeaconScanContext.Builder()
            .setEventTypes(eventTypes) //only specified events we be called on callback
            .setRssiCalculator(RssiCalculators.newLimitedMeanRssiCalculator(5))
            .build();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        proximityManager = new KontaktProximityManager(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shop);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setTitle("Shopping");

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.tab_content);

        MapTabContentFragment mtcf = new MapTabContentFragment();
        adapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        IndoorsFactory.Builder indoorsBuilder = new IndoorsFactory.Builder();
        IndoorsSurfaceFactory.Builder surfaceBuilder = new IndoorsSurfaceFactory.Builder();
        indoorsBuilder.setContext(this);

        // Set the API Key for Indoo.rs
        indoorsBuilder.setApiKey(getResources().getString(R.string.indoors_api_key));

        // Set the building's ID
        indoorsBuilder.setBuildingId((long)762751544);
        // Log.d(TAG+ " Building ID: ", Long.toString(pBuildingID));

        // callback for indoo.rs-events
        indoorsBuilder.setUserInteractionListener(this);
        surfaceBuilder.setIndoorsBuilder(indoorsBuilder);
        indoorsFragment = surfaceBuilder.build();

        adapter.addFragment(new ListTabContentFragment(), "LIST");
        adapter.addFragment(indoorsFragment, "MAP");
        adapter.addFragment(new ARTabContentFragment(), "AR");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
}
```

This code segment just loads all the tabs at once when the activity is created. Now what I need is the 2nd fragment (mtcf, "MAP") to load only when the beacons signal is received.

```
@Override
public void onEvent(BluetoothDeviceEvent bluetoothDeviceEvent) {
    List<? extends RemoteBluetoothDevice> deviceList = bluetoothDeviceEvent.getDeviceList();
    long timestamp = bluetoothDeviceEvent.getTimestamp();
    DeviceProfile deviceProfile = bluetoothDeviceEvent.getDeviceProfile();
    switch (bluetoothDeviceEvent.getEventType()) {
        case SPACE_ENTERED:
            Log.d(TAG, "namespace or region entered");
            break;
        case DEVICE_DISCOVERED:
            Log.d(TAG, "found new beacon");
            Log.d(TAG, ((Integer.toString(deviceList.size()))));

            String nameOfBeacon = deviceList.get(0).getName();

            if(nameOfBeacon.equals("Entrance")) {
                long buildingMapID = lookupBuilding(deviceList.get(0).getName());
                IndoorsSurfaceFragment indoorsSurfaceFragment = createIndoorFragment(buildingMapID);

                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.indoorslayout,indoorsSurfaceFragment).commit();
            }
            break;
```

MapFragment.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/indoorslayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>`
```

How can I implement this?? I need the map fragment to load only after the Bluetooth beacon event is received.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must handle it by your `TabPagerAdapter`:

1, In TabPagerAdapter, add a param, like : `List<Fragment> mItems`, first you add two fragments into mItems.

override `TabPagerAdapter`getItem function like this:

```
 public Fragment getItem(int position){
     return mItems.get(position);
}
```

2, When you want to show MapFragment, just by `TabPagerAdapter` addItem function, then mItems have three fragments. You can manually sort fragments.

When you use `addItem`, don't forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.
Hope to help you!

Comment: Been searching along the wrong way for the last two days. Thanks again.

Comment: There is one more problem. Is it possible to replace a new fragment with an old one? I tried something like this. mFragmentList.set(1,newFragment);

But it is not getting updated. I have called the notifyDataSetChanged() function also. Any reason why?

Comment: Yes, `notifyDataSetChanged()` always don't work, when your adapter extends `FragmentPagerAdapter`. You should override `getItemPosition`, and return `POSITION_NONE`. You can refer:[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849552/update-viewpager-dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke notifyDataSetChanged inside "OnEvent" , and implement 
getItemPosition(Object map) in Viewpager.

This will update the map page everytime you invode notifyDatasetChanged
[Update Fragment from ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088076/update-fragment-from-viewpager)

Comment: Mark the question as answered.

Comment: Hello, I have selected the best answer above, since he answered the same thing, before you. Thanks for the help btw. :)