# Accessing fragment view on orientation change

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, orientation-changes

I am implementing a ViewPager using FragmentStatePagerAdapter. The code samples are below.

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Log.d("--GetItem", "---");

        switch (position) {

            case 0:
                return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance(b1);
            case 1:
                return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance(b2);
            case 2:
                return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance(b3);
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Log.d("--InstItem", "--");
        return super.instantiateItem(container, position);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES; //set as 3
    }


}
```

**ScreenSlidePageFragment**  is as follows.

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{


    Bundle b;

    public ScreenSlidePageFragment() {

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.d("----onCreateFrgmnt--", "11");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.d("----onCreateViewFrgmnt-", "11");

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);

        return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        Log.d("----onViewCreatedFrgmnt", "11");


        b = getArguments();

        TextView tv_city = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.city_field);
        TextView tv_update = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.updated_field);
        TextView tv_day = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.day);

        tv_day.setText("DAY " + String.valueOf(b.getInt("day")));
        tv_city.setText(b.getString("city"));

        tv_update.setText("Last update on : " + b.getString("date"));

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    public static ScreenSlidePageFragment newInstance(Bundle myBundle) {

        ScreenSlidePageFragment f = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
        f.setArguments(myBundle);
        return f;
    }
}
```

In the **MainActivity**, I am trying to handle the orientation change. I use the following piece of code.

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myViewPager = (MyCustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);


    b1 = savedInstanceState.getBundle("Fragment1");
    b2 = savedInstanceState.getBundle("Fragment2");
    b3 = savedInstanceState.getBundle("Fragment3");



    myViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(NUM_PAGES - 1);

    myPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    myViewPager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);

}
```

The fragments are recreated on orientation change. **onCreateView** as well as **onViewCreated** are being called (checked LogCat). The problem arises when I try to update the view in the fragments. For the update I am using following code:

```
FragmentStatePagerAdapter adapter = (FragmentStatePagerAdapter) myViewPager.getAdapter();

ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment1 = (ScreenSlidePageFragment) adapter.instantiateItem(myViewPager, 0);
ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment2 = (ScreenSlidePageFragment) adapter.instantiateItem(myViewPager, 1);
ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment3 = (ScreenSlidePageFragment) adapter.instantiateItem(myViewPager, 2);
```

But when I call **fragment1.getView()**, it is returning null. However, the same code runs well when I don't change the orientation.

How can I get the fragment views on orientation change? I checked some of the solutions posted where they say to save the fragments in array, but those are not working for me. Are the codes I have put, not able to do the task? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't update the fragments (which only happens on orientation change) your code will run fine.

However, your update code will always return `null` for `getView()` as the views haven't been created yet. `instantiateItem()` will create a new `Fragment` when called, that hasn't been added to your application yet and such all the lifecycle callbacks (including `onCreateView(...)` and `onViewCreated(...)`) haven't been called yet.

Due to the complexity of correctly updating a `ViewPager`'s fragments I'll refer you to an excellent [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18088509/5731450). You can also find more details in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849552/update-viewpager-dynamically).