# Refresh fragment when change between tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments

App open on first fragment and there is 2 tabs i want to refresh second fragment 
when i move to it but i don't want to refresh first fragment

### MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Main_Button(), "Main");
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "Main2");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

please explain your answer because i'm new in android and i don't know how i can do that

Answer (score 47, accepted):

When a `Fragment` is made visible (i.e., the selected page in your `ViewPager`), its [setUserVisibleHint()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean)) method is called. You can override that method in your `TwoFragment` and use it to trigger a refresh.

```
public class TwoFragment extends Fragment {

  @Override
  public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
      // Refresh your fragment here
    }
  }
```

Comment: great example Thanks you

Comment: This method works good, except, when I have for example swiping tablayout and user swipes to switch between tabs, there is a delay with the refresh, since it starts to refresh the view when its completly swiped to the other fragment. I have noticed that because I have circle progress bar with loading animation, and it looks stupid when I swipe. I have to tap tablayout tabs and then it refreshes nicely. Any idea how to solve this? I think it needs to destroy tab which is off screen, then it would load nicely, but how?

Comment: I have tried to add `else{
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).commit();` but when I swipe to other fragment, it is completly empty for a second, then it start drawing all the views.... any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Good solution, but the method is now deprecated. Do you have an idea how to use user visibility idea with newer methods?

Comment: As per the deprecation, you'll want to use `onResume()` as the signal that you're visible

Answer (score 32):

Inside Your fragment class use the below code:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 2020 it is advisable to use architecture components(MVVM) such as LiveData and viewModel

This way all Fragments can share the same state

see docs here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide

Answer (score 1):

Try this - it works for me

This code reloads current fragment, when it visible to user. Works when swiping and when back button pressed on next fragment.

```js
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisible) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisible);
        if (isVisible) {
                FragmentTransaction ftr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ftr.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wouldn't mind refreshing every fragment every time a tab changes, you could simply override the `getItemPosition()` method of your FragmentPagerAdapter and make it return always the value `POSITION_NONE`. Example:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
   return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

By doing that, you tell android to refresh the fragment each time the view pager tries to get it. Performance wise, it isn't the best practice. So there is a second approach:

First, create an interface to be called when your need refresh:

```
public interface Updatable {
   public void update();
}
```

Then, make your fragments implement this interface:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements Updateable {

   ...

   @Override
   public void update() {
     // refresh your fragment, if needed
   }
}
```

If your really wish to *not* update your first fragment, do nothing in its `update()` method.

Third, override the `getItemPosition` method and call `update()`. This will be called every time a fragment gets selected:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
   Updatable f = (Updatable) object;
   if (f != null) {
      f.update();
   }
  return super.getItemPosition(object);
}
```

Most of this code came from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088076/update-fragment-from-viewpager).

Answer (score 0):

you could use ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener to listen to when the fragments are swiped and incorporate some type of action there.

Comment: Hi there, Shaun. While the point you make may be accurate, try including a small code snippet for the answer to have better reach.