# Force sending data using SharedPreferences( fragment to fragment in PagerAdapter)

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I'm using `SharedPreferences` to store and send data from a fragment to 4 other fragments, but my problem is when the app is running and I send the data on click button it takes the other fragments sometime to actually receive the data ( or when swipe through the pages after 3 or 4 swipes they update) I have tried `setUserVisibleHint`in each fragment and `onpagechangelistener` in the activity but nothing changes. How can I make the other fragments to recieve the data as I swipe to the pages or as I press the button?

**note:** I don't want to put buttons in each fragment to load the data.

**sender:**

```
   int riddle;
   Context context = getActivity();
   SharedPreferences SU = context.getSharedPreferences(
                        "Riddle", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor= SU.edit();
   editor.putString("Riddle",""+riddle);
   editor.commit();
```

**other fragments:**

```
      int Riddle;
      Context context = getActivity();
      SharedPreferences SU = context.getSharedPreferences(
                "Riddle", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      Riddle=  Integer.parseInt(SU.getString("riddle",""));
```

**UPDATE**
 I made a mistake in the original post , the sender should be:

```
    int riddle;
   Context context = getActivity();
   SharedPreferences SU = context.getSharedPreferences(
                        "Riddle", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor= SU.edit();
   editor.putString("riddle",""+riddle);
   editor.commit();
```

because of the key thing.

one problem remains, the fragment im sending the data from is the last page(page 5) and when i send the data , the page next to it (page 4) doesnt update till i swipe to page 3 and come back to it

Comment: Instead of   Context context = getActivity() you can use fragments getContext() right?

Comment: Also change  editor.commit() to  editor.apply() and check if the problem solves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
Riddle=  Integer.parseInt(SU.getString("Riddle",""));
```

instead of this

```
Riddle=  Integer.parseInt(SU.getString("riddle",""));
```

Comment: sorry for that and thank you for pointing it out, still one problem the page next to the "sender" page doesnt reload

Comment: @amirsoltani can you explain more

Comment: yes I'm using viewpager so the fragment im sending the data from is the last page(page 5) and when i send the data , the page next to the page im sending the data from (page 4) doesnt update till i swipe to page 3 and come back to it

Comment: @amirsoltani try this `viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged() `

Comment: @amirsoltani form more information check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088076/update-fragment-from-viewpager

Answer (score 2):

Use same key for getting data from `SharedPreferences` which is used in sender. change :

```
Riddle=  Integer.parseInt(SU.getString("riddle",""));
                                        ^^^^^
```

to

```
Riddle=  Integer.parseInt(SU.getString("Riddle",""));
```

Comment: oh yea im sorry that was a mistake thank you for pointing it out, still one problem the page next to the "sender" page doesnt reload