# ViewPager with instant refresh android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager and its child fragments are dynamic. I am using them in the same fragment class and I am changing the field's value dynamically. But when I changing the ViewPager position, It is not updating the fragment. I have to change the values instantly.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to recreate fragments on every swipe, than in your viewPager you can add this code     ----            mPage.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update Fragment from ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088076/update-fragment-from-viewpager)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `refreshFragment` method in your fragment class then

In `ViewPagerAdapter` class overwritte method

```
@Override
    public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) {
       MyFragment f = (MyFragment ) object;
        if (f != null) {
           f.refreshFragment();
        }
        return super.getItemPosition(object);
    }
```

When you call

```
viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

it will call `getItemPosition` method in adapter class and update your fragment using refreshFragment method.

Answer (score 0):

Android by default retains one page on both sides of the current page for optimised loading. Since you need the pages to refresh on every time, you need to use `viewpager.setOffScreenPageLimit(0)` to set all pages to be recreated every time they are viewed