# Refresh ListFragment in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-listfragment, survey

I am creating a survey app based on [WizarDroid](http://goo.gl/UnUa3C). I am using a `ViewPager` and the questions are loaded dynamically in each fragment in the ViewPager.

The ViewPager creates 3 fragments: "Pre", "Current" and "Next".

I am having a problem with the "Next" fragment because my last fragment is a ListFragment (AnswerReviewList) so the list cannot update the last question and answer because it is already created.

Is it possible to refresh the list (ReviewListfragment) from a ViewPager listener method?

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {}
```

Please ask if you don't understand my question.

ReviewListFragment.java

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("############################ last fragment ",
            "onActivityCreated");
    queArrListVO = ((EventSurveyActivity) getActivity()).surveyQuetionVOList;
    adptrReviewQuestion = new SurveysReviewBaseAdapter(
            getSherlockActivity(), queArrListVO);
    getListView().setAdapter(adptrReviewQuestion);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);

    setEmptyText(" :) ");
    setListShown(true);
}
```

Comment: @blackbelt please answer my question If you know

Answer (score 1):

If your `SurveysReviewBaseAdapter` extends from [`BaseAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) (which I'll assume given the name of the class), you can use [`BaseAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) to reload the ListAdapter with the new data in, for example, `onResume`.

Comment: thanks for answer problem is that i can not do like this because fragment is already created in ViewPager and onResume()  of ListFragment called before new data i fill data in Fragment

Comment: Can you access the adapter (e.g., using [`Fragment.getListAdapter()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#getListAdapter())) after you "fill the data in Fragment"? Because you could just call it then...

Comment: yes i can do this but i am doing that than i get nullPointerException because SurveysReviewBaseAdapter is my custom adapter  http://pastie.org/private/cttrybhoypqlc1i8po7aig#5-8 see code in both method i got same error

Comment: Forget what I said about notifyDatasetChanged. Can you use [`viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)) and see if that works?

Comment: its still create next fragment i have create Log when i am on getCount()-1 page at that time getCount() number page all methods are called

Comment: hey @menno i have tried as you say but see this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073214/viewpager-setoffscreenpagelimit0-doesnt-work-as-expected