# OncreateView Issue

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an application with a fragments. In one activity there is 3 fragment which is frag1,frag2 and frag3 . It is possible that The OncreateView will trigger is just for frag1 only . In my case frag1 and frag2 are the first to read the onCreateView Event. I just want the frag1 only and when you swipe the frag2 will read and so on.

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Are you using a ViewPager? In that case by default, the previous and next fragment will be created

Comment: `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` has method `abstract void  onPageSelected(int position)` you can trigger to mark as read or load text when you change page

Comment: @Chol Yes.  But I want that only one will be created . Is that possible?

Comment: You should use viewPager.setOffScreenPageLimit http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29, but I'm not sure you will be able to set it to 0

Answer (score 0):

With the viewPager you are able to set the number of fragment created with the method `setOffScreenPageLimit` but unfortunatly I think you will not be able to create only one fragment (the one visible). What will happen when you will slide? As the second fragment is not created, a blank screen...
To be smoothy when scrolling, the second fragment view has to be already created.

Check this response: [ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0) doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073214/viewpager-setoffscreenpagelimit0-doesnt-work-as-expected)

Comment: Yes, when i scroll to the other one . it will create the one that I will view. and the other will destroy.