# How to remove the fragment from its calling fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

How to remove the fragment from his calling fragment ?

i have search this thing but i didn't get solution according to my requirement. In my application, there is one `FragmentActivity` which has the `viewPager`.

This `viewPager` contains 3 Fragments. For fragment I am using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

Suppose there is 3 fragment: `A`, `B`, `C`; and `D` fragment `C` also contain a child fragment `E`.

I have call fragment `E` in the `onCreateView()` method and in the `onDestroy()` method of fragment `C`, I have remove the child fragment `E`.

So what is happening when I slid `viewPager` from `C` to `B`, and `B` to `A` - when I come back from `A` to `B`, now current displaying fragment is `B`. Now if I slid fragment `C` should be display, but in place of fragment `C` the child fragment of `C`, fragment `E` is displaying after then fragment `E` then fragment C is displaying now in this condition i have not seen Fragment E over the fragment `C`, the child fragment `E` is not interacting with `viewpager` but why it is added in viewPager,

i have try to destroy the child fragment `E` in `onPause()` and in `onDestroy()` method of `C`, but nothing is happening. Please any one help me.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    MYDataManager.sharedHandler().changeLanguageConfiguration();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_open_translate, R.anim.activity_close_scale);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_myscanner);

    appFlow = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(MYConstant.kProfileMenuSettings, MYConstant.kScanner, MYConstant.kRestaurantListing));

    viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
    viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);

    reloadViewPager(1);
}

public void reloadViewPager(int currentItem) {
    adapter = new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return getFragmentWithPosition(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return appFlow.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
    };
    viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewpager.setCurrentItem(currentItem);
}

private MYBaseFragment getFragmentWithPosition(int position) {
    String screen = appFlow.get(position);
    MYBaseFragment fragment = null;
    if(screen.equals(MYConstant.kProfileMenuSettings)) {
        myProfileSettingFragment = new MYProfileSettingFragment();
        fragment = myProfileSettingFragment;
    } else if(screen.equals(MYConstant.kScanner)) {
        fragment = new MYScannerParentFragment();
    } else if(screen.equals(MYConstant.kRestaurantListing)) {
        myRestaurantListFragment = new MYRestaurantListFragment();
        fragment = myRestaurantListFragment;
    } else if(screen.equals(MYConstant.kRestaurantDetails)) {
        myResraurantDetailsFragment = new MYResraurantDetailsFragment();
        fragment = myResraurantDetailsFragment;
    } else if(screen.equals(MYConstant.kCurrentRestaurantDetails)) {
        MYQRCode qrData = MYDataManager.sharedHandler().getQRData();
        if(MYUitilities.checkQRValidation(qrData)) {
            fragment = new MYCurResDetails();
        }
    } else if(screen.equals(MYConstant.kSettings)) {
        fragment = new MYSettingFragment();
    } else if(screen.equals(MYConstant.kViewMenu)) {
        fragment = new MYResCatListFragment();
    } else if(screen.equals(MYConstant.kMenuCategoryListing)) {
        fragment = new MYResCatListFragment();
    } else if(screen.equals(MYConstant.kViewMenuViewPage)) {
        // myResMenuViewPagerFragment =  new MYResMenuViewPagerFragment();
        // fragment = myResMenuViewPagerFragment;
        fragment = new MYResMenuViewPagerFragment();
    } else if(screen.equals(MYConstant.kReviewOrder)) {
        fragment = new MYReviewOrderFragment();
    } else if(screen.equals(MYConstant.kYourOrder)) {
        fragment = new MYYourOrderFragment();
    } else if(screen.equals(MYConstant.kSettings)) {
        fragment = new MYSettingFragment();
    } else if(screen.equals(MYConstant.kOrderHistory)) {
        fragment = new MYOrderHistoryFragment();
    } else if(screen.equals(MYConstant.kCheckout)) {
        fragment = new MYCheckoutFragment();
    } else if(screen.equals(MYConstant.kCallWaiter)) {
        fragment = new MYCallWaiterFragment();
    } else if(screen.equals(MYConstant.kYourProfile)) {
        myYourProfileFragment = new MYYourProfileFragment();
        fragment = myYourProfileFragment;
    }

    fragment.setFragmentInteractionListener(MYScannerActivity.this);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
    if(currentPosition >= 0) {
        final String previousScreen = appFlow.get(currentPosition);
        final String currentScreen = appFlow.get(position);

        System.out.println("previousScreen-" + previousScreen);
        System.out.println("currentScreen-" + currentScreen);

        if(previousScreen.equals(MYConstant.kYourProfile) && currentScreen.equals(MYConstant.kProfileMenuSettings)) {
            appFlow.remove(MYConstant.kYourProfile);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            viewpager.setCurrentItem(0);
        }
        if(previousScreen.equals(MYConstant.kRestaurantDetails) && currentScreen.equals(MYConstant.kRestaurantListing)) {
            appFlow.remove(MYConstant.kRestaurantDetails);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else if(previousScreen.equals(MYConstant.kViewMenu) && currentScreen.equals(MYConstant.kRestaurantDetails)) {
            appFlow.remove(MYConstant.kViewMenu);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else if(previousScreen.equals(MYConstant.kViewMenuViewPage) && currentScreen.equals(MYConstant.kViewMenu)) {
            appFlow.remove(MYConstant.kViewMenuViewPage);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else if(previousScreen.equals(MYConstant.kViewMenuViewPage) && currentScreen.equals(MYConstant.kMenuCategoryListing)) {
            appFlow.remove(MYConstant.kViewMenuViewPage);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else if(previousScreen.equals(MYConstant.kYourOrder) && currentScreen.equals(MYConstant.kViewMenuViewPage)) {
            appFlow.remove(MYConstant.kYourOrder);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else if(previousScreen.equals(MYConstant.kReviewOrder) && currentScreen.equals(MYConstant.kViewMenuViewPage)) {
            appFlow.remove(MYConstant.kReviewOrder);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else if(previousScreen.equals(MYConstant.kYourOrder) && currentScreen.equals(MYConstant.kReviewOrder)) {
            appFlow.remove(MYConstant.kYourOrder);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else if(previousScreen.equals(MYConstant.kYourOrder) && currentScreen.equals(MYConstant.kViewMenuViewPage)) {
            appFlow.remove(MYConstant.kReviewOrder);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else if(previousScreen.equals(MYConstant.kSettings) && currentScreen.equals(MYConstant.kProfileMenuSettings)) {
            appFlow.remove(MYConstant.kSettings);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            viewpager.setCurrentItem(0);
        } else if(previousScreen.equals(MYConstant.kOrderHistory) && currentScreen.equals(MYConstant.kProfileMenuSettings)) {
            appFlow.remove(MYConstant.kOrderHistory);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            viewpager.setCurrentItem(0);
        } else if(previousScreen.equals(MYConstant.kCheckout) && currentScreen.equals(MYConstant.kViewMenuViewPage)) {
            appFlow.remove(MYConstant.kCheckout);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else if(previousScreen.equals(MYConstant.kCheckout) && currentScreen.equals(MYConstant.kReviewOrder)) {
            appFlow.remove(MYConstant.kCheckout);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else if(previousScreen.equals(MYConstant.kCheckout) && currentScreen.equals(MYConstant.kYourOrder)) {
            appFlow.remove(MYConstant.kCheckout);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else if(previousScreen.equals(MYConstant.kCallWaiter) && currentScreen.equals(MYConstant.kCheckout)) {
            appFlow.remove(MYConstant.kCallWaiter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else if(previousScreen.equals(MYConstant.kRestaurantListing) && currentScreen.equals(MYConstant.kScanner)) {
            if(MYDataManager.sharedHandler().isQRCodeScanned()) {
                appFlow.remove(MYConstant.kRestaurantListing);
                if(!appFlow.contains(MYConstant.kCurrentRestaurantDetails)) {
                    appFlow.add(MYConstant.kCurrentRestaurantDetails);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        } else if(previousScreen.equals(MYConstant.kCurrentRestaurantDetails) && currentScreen.equals(MYConstant.kScanner)) {

        } else if(previousScreen.equals(MYConstant.kMenuCategoryListing) && currentScreen.equals(MYConstant.kCurrentRestaurantDetails)) {
            appFlow.remove(MYConstant.kMenuCategoryListing);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    Fragment fragment = ((FragmentStatePagerAdapter) viewpager.getAdapter()).getItem(position);
    if(fragment instanceof MYProfileSettingFragment) {

    }
    currentPosition = position;
}
```

Comment: I think you should use custom viewgroups and a normal `ViewPager` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, that way you will be in direct control of all state.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce the fragment  'MYScannerParentFragment' contain the   fragment  'E', fragment 'E' not related to 'viewPager' but after sliding fragment 'E' removed from  'MYScannerParentFragment' and displaying left side the 'MYScannerParentFragment'.

Answer (score 0):

You Please try these.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);

                fragmentTransaction.remove(currentFragment);//remove current fragment
```

Comment: this thing is not working for me, here it is sowing currentFragment = null.

Comment: you must have to add name to u r gragment

Comment: where i have to add fragment name? I have tried with Tag but its not removing the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

> So what is happening when I slid viewPager from C to B, and B to A - when I come back from A to B, now current displaying fragment is B.

I had faced something before like you have now. I was registering and unregistereing a listener on fragments life cycle events. But in viewpager, even i switched to another fragment, the previously fragment never be destroyed, you can [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059742/how-to-manage-otto-registration-methods-in-viewpager)

Before dive into your case, i wanna mention about 'off page limit'. So you cant set to zero. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073214/viewpager-setoffscreenpagelimit0-doesnt-work-as-expected/10073916#10073916). So when you set 0, **it defaults to 1**

```
viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
```

If im not missing something, in this case, when you switch from C to B

- If you had visited D fragment before C, D will be destroyed, B will be created, C still will be living.

Assuming you coming from first case (C to B, and then B to A)

- C will be destroyed, B lives, A will be created

Bottom line, with ViewPager you have min two fragments. One is you are currently interacting and second (screen off)

Comment: @
Blackkara  you are not getting my problem let me explain you the Fragment C contain fragment E and E is not related to viewPager . when fragment C is visible is call the Fragment E inside the onCreateView method of C. problem is that when Fragment C has destroyed by viewPager the fragment E which is called by C is not destroyed it is automatically added left side the Fragment C. so requirement is that when C has destroyed E should be destroyed again when C become visible E should also visible over the C.

Comment: So my post refers that FragmentC have to be responsible for creating and removing FragmentE in your case. Add dynamically fragment E when Fragment C appeared, then remove dynamically fragment E when fragment C disappeared.

Comment: yes it is my requirements what fragment E automatically removed from C and added left side the C why it is happening?