# Viewpager with different menu and common toolbar not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have tabs in my app. Each tab is of different fragments and has different menu. Below is the layout which I am using

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/background">

            <include
                layout="@layout/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <com.CustomViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:background="@color/background"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/view_pager"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            app:layout_behavior="com.widget.ScrollTabBehavior"
            app:tabBackground="@color/background"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/toolbar"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
            app:tabPaddingStart="0dp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-64dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="-64dp"
        android:background="@color/toolbar"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/close_btn"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/close_icon" />

        <view
            android:id="@+id/drawerlist"
            class="android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/close_btn" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now with every Fragment in `onCreate()` I have mentioned `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` further more. I have overriden the function `onCreateOptionsMenu()` in each fragment which has `menu.clear();` at first then calling it's super constructor then inflating fragment's own menu xml. But result I am getting is something like this -

- Suppose there are 5 tabs. 2nd and 3rd tab has viewpager within each consist of two more fragments within
- 1st tab has no menu
- 2nd tab has menu_2 (only for 2nd child fragment)
- 3rd tab again has no menu
- 4th tab has menu_4 (only for 1st child fragment)
- 5th tab has menu_5
- Initially, there should be no menu for tab 1 which is ok. Then moving to 3rd tab directly it shows menu_4 which by default should show no menu. Then sliding to tab 4, it will show proper menu_4 then sliding back to 3rd tab it will show no menu (which is as required).
- This same thing happens for tab 5. If I am switching to 2nd child fragment within 2nd tab then the same behavior is observed with 1st tab.

In short, according to my observation it is showing the menu of adjacent tabs which is actually getting executed after the current fragment and therefore such behavior is occurring.

So how to avoid this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have written small test-application to check the behaviour.

[image]

Let's go through the sample and see, if something wrong with your fragments (as you see above, ViewPager with different menus works like a charm)

`Activity`'s XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

`Activity` class. Important part is `invalidateOptionsMenu()` every time `ViewPager` has PageSelected event. Then, we setting `setHasOptionsMenu` to all fragments and *subfragments*(from the nested `ViewPager`s) to `false` if they out of screen.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Fragment[] fragments = {
                Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentNoMenu.class.getName()),
                Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentA.class.getName()),
                Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentNoMenu.class.getName()),
                Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentB.class.getName()),
        };

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu(position);
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
        });

        invalidateOptionsMenu(0);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void invalidateOptionsMenu(int position) {
        for(int i = 0; i < pagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            Fragment fragment = pagerAdapter.getItem(i);
            fragment.setHasOptionsMenu(i == position);

            if (fragment instanceof FragmentWithViewPager) {
                FragmentWithViewPager fragmentWithViewPager = (FragmentWithViewPager)fragment;
                if (fragmentWithViewPager.pagerAdapter != null) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < fragmentWithViewPager.pagerAdapter.getCount(); j++) {
                        fragmentWithViewPager.pagerAdapter.getItem(j).setHasOptionsMenu(i == position);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
}
```

`PagerAdapter` class:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final Fragment[] fragments;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Fragment[] fragments) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragments[position].getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.length;
    }
}
```

Here're my test fragments I used:

`FragmentNoMenu` class:

```
public class FragmentNoMenu extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_no_menu, container, false);
    }
}
```

`FragmentNoMenu` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#0F0F50"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

`FragmentA` class is a Fragment with nested ViewPager:

```
public class FragmentA extends FragmentWithViewPager {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

        Fragment[] fragments = {
                Fragment.instantiate(getContext(), SubFragmentA.class.getName()),
                Fragment.instantiate(getContext(), SubFragmentB.class.getName()),
                Fragment.instantiate(getContext(), SubFragmentC.class.getName()),
        };

        if (pagerAdapter == null) {
            pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), fragments);
        }

        viewPager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_a, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
}
```

`FragmentA`'s layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#B0B0B0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

`FragmentA`'s menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_item_1"
        android:title="Item 1"
        android:orderInCategory="250"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_item_2"
        android:title="Item 2"
        android:orderInCategory="300"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

NB! `FragmentA` extends `FragmentWithViewPager` - it's a small extension of `Fragment` to make it easier to distinguish Fragments with nested fragments in MainActivity:

```
public class FragmentWithViewPager extends Fragment {
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    ViewPager viewPager;
}
```

`FragmentB`:

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_b, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
}
```

It's layout & menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#999999"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

.....

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_item3"
        android:title="Item 3"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_triage_star"
        android:orderInCategory="250"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Subfragments (they are all look the same from the code perspective):

Layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#AA0000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="SubFragment C (with icon Menu)"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#00BB00"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Code:

```
public class SubFragmentB extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.subfragment_b, container, false);
    }
}
```

That's it! I've uploaded the project to my dropbox - [feel free to check it out](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xijfbgskmqu3so6/ViewPagerWithDifferentMenuUpd.zip?dl=0)!

I hope, it helps

Comment: This is what I have as working code... Problem is with viewpager within viewpager...

Comment: @JimitPatel Now I see the problem. Luckily, it's fixable: the idea is to setHasOptionsMenu for all fragments & subfragments, which are out of screen & invalidateOptionsMenu afterwards every time ViewPager is changing it's page. I've updated my code, files, preview image. Check it out!

Comment: This way it worked with I was having one view pager as whole. But if I had view pager within view pager, at that time it didn't worked out. So I made only one menu and made it in/visible at times when required.