# ViewPager not initialising fragment when needed

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` with three tabs. In each of the tabs there is a list of movies.

I made it so there is one fragment that contains the `ListView` and every time the user chooses a tab, a static reference in the `MainActivity` changes, causing the adapter of the list view to refresh with other types of data.

So it's designed like this:

**MovieListFragment:** a fragment containing a list view and initialising it.
**PagerAdapter:** the adapter for the view pager. In the `getItem` method, it simply returns a new instance of the `MovieListFragment`.
**MoviesFragment:** This is the fragment that holds everything together. It initialises the tabs and the ViewPager and connects them. It also adds a listener for tab select, changing the dataType for the list view accordingly.

By adding logs, I found that the dataType does change correctly.
However, the `onCreateView` in the MovieListFragment **is not called every time a tab is selected.** Thus, the adapter is not refreshing so the list shown is not with the correct dataType.

How do I create the fragment every time a tab is selected, so I can correctly set the dataType for the list view in that specific tab?

Comment: Are you using FragmentPagerAdapter? It reuses the fragment so `onCreateView` will not be called every time, that's expected.

Comment: @Vucko I am. Yes, that's exactly the problem. How do I get around it?

Comment: Just have your Custom adapter extend FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Comment: @Vucko Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073214/viewpager-setoffscreenpagelimit0-doesnt-work-as-expected/25676323#25676323

Comment: @DimitrisKonomis That's great, but it seems that the `setUserVisibleHint` is faster than the dataType updating on select of the tab. I mean, it fires the function before I can set the correct dataType according to the tab selection.

Comment: You can use a handler for that. Also try to use mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0); but i don't know if its gone work cause i can't use my laptop right now and i can't test it

Comment: Thanks! Ended up using a handler with a 10ms delay. It works now, but it feels like a dirty solution.