# How to set viewpager load only one page and setOffscreenPageLimit() android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

How to set viewpager load only one page and setOffscreenPageLimit() android

I want to load viewpager load only one page in one time and I want to disable reload page when this page is visible(loaded).

yes, I know if want to load only one page is use  `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);`

but I dont know to set disable reload page when this page is visible(loaded).

> Example
>
> my app have 3 page in viewpager (page1,Page2,Page3)
>
> when app start -> page 1 is loading
>
> and when i click tab 2(never opened) -> page 2 is loading
>
> and when i click tab 3(never opened) -> page 3 is loading
>
> and when I swipe to page2, page1 (opened) is not reload

How to set it? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1)` is the default setting without you doing anything to it. `1` stands for [the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)), i.e. if you are on page n, the `ViewPager` will load page n -1 and page n + 1. Using the default `ViewPager`, there is no way to set the offscreen page limit to `0` nor get the wanted behaviour otherwise (while you are able to swipe). See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10073916/3356270).