# Airbnb epoxy with Viewpager and Youtubeplayer

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, epoxy

I have a `Viewpager` which extends `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` with 2 fragments (each has `com.airbnb.epoxy.EpoxyRecyclerView`)

Used `Airbnb's Expoxy` library to populate `heterogeneous recyclerview`

The `1st fragment` has `youtube player` (library used https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player) which plays video on start of screen

This youtube library takes care of `youtubeplayer` lifecycle by adding `fragment.lifecycle.addObserver(youtubePlayer)`

**Issue**

When I swipe to `2nd fragment` the video still plays in `1st fragment`

**My findings**

On swipe of `viewpager` to `2nd fragment` , `the 1st fragment` doesn't goes to `onPause()` state

**What I did**

I tried setting `viewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 0` , but no use

Comment: Fragment does not pause on swiping . Try overriding `setUserVisibleHint()` to check if Fragment is visible to use or not .. Or Alternatively you can pass a callback from `OnPageChangeListener`...

Comment: Also Check [ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0) doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073214/viewpager-setoffscreenpagelimit0-doesnt-work-as-expected).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really have to do anything with epoxy or the youtube library. ViewPager on android loads the adjacent fragments so onResume/onPause don't work as you'd expect in a ViewPager. Are you using AndroidX? If you are I recommend using the latest version of appcompat, currently `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-beta02`.

`FragmentStatePagerAdapter` has a new constructor:
`FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT)`

Which will properly call onResume/onPause on fragments inside ViewPager resulting in a better experience in your case.

Comment: @karthikkolanji let me know how you go :)

Comment: I used MVI architecture , so everything is state related . I passed pause=true or false as state via setUserVisibleHint()